# A question about the test statistic for testing the difference in two population proportions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, mathematical-statistics, asymptotics

For independent samples $X_1,\cdots,X_n $from $\textit{Bernoulli }(p_1)$
and $Y_1,\cdots,Y_m$ from $\textit{Bernoulli }(p_2)$,where $n$ and $m$ are large.
Then,the *Central Limit Theorem* tell us $\frac{\bar X_n-p_1}{\sqrt{\frac{p_1(1-p_1)}{n}}}$ converges in distribution to $\textit{Normal }(0,1)$ and $\frac{\bar Y_m-p_2}{\sqrt{\frac{p_2(1-p_2)}{m}}}$ converges in distribution to $\textit{Normal } (0,1)$.Can we get $\frac{(\bar X_n-\bar Y_m)-(p_1-p_2)}{\sqrt{\frac{p_1(1-p_1)}{n}+\frac{p_2(1-p_2)}{m}}} $ converges in distribution to $\textit{Normal }(0,1)$, when $n$ and $m$ are large enough?

I cannot find some conclusions said that if $X_n$ converges in distribution to $X$ and $Y_n$ converges in distribution to $Y$,then $X_n\pm Y_{n}$ converges in distribution to  $X\pm Y.$

In hypothesis test concerning the difference between two population proportions,
we consider two binomial populations with parameters $n$, $p_1$ and $m$, $p_2$, respectively, where $n$ and $m$ are large. Then, we are usually interested in testing hypotheses such as $$H_0: p_1 − p_2 \leq 0 \quad\textrm{versus}\quad H_1: p_1 − p_2 > 0 \quad (a)$$$$H_0: p_1 − p_2 \geq 0 \quad\textrm{ versus}\quad H_1: p_1 − p_2 < 0 \quad (b)$$$$H_0: p_1 − p_2 = 0 \quad\textrm{ versus}\quad H_1: p_1 − p_2 \ne 0 \quad (c)$$
Why we assume that
the test statistic $T= 
\frac{(\hat{p}_1-\hat{p}_2)-(p_1-p_2)}{\sqrt{\frac{p_1(1-p_1)}{n}+\frac{p_2(1-p_2)}{m}}}$,where $\hat{p}_1=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}$and $\hat{p}_2=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{k=1}^{m}y_{k}$, is approximately distributed by the standard
normal $\textit{Normal }(0, 1)$?

Comment: There are several versions of this test. One uses the separate variances estimate of the standard error of your $T$ and another uses $p_1 = p_2$ from the null hypothesis. The latter estimates $p$ by $\tilde p = \frac{\sum X_i+\sum Y_i}{n+m}$ and gets the denominator of the test statistic from there. // The first version has the advantage that one 95% CI for $p_1-p_2$ does not contain $0$ precisely when $H_0$ is rejected at the 5% level. (That is, 'inverting the test' at 5% level, gives a 95% CI.) This version seems to be equivalent to `prop.test` in R, if 'continuity correction' is declined.

Comment: Not sure, but maybe halfway through your question, you're looking for [Slutsky's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem). Also, the second version of the test is discussed on [this page](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/software/dataplot/refman1/auxillar/binotest.htm) of the NIST Handbook. (Notation differs from yours, but it's the same thing.)

Answer (score 2):

Comments continued to show Examples of `prop.test` and `chisq.test` in R:

(1) $\hat p_1 = 20/100$ is not significantly different from $\hat p_2 = 48/200$ at 5% level.

```
prop.test(c(20,48), c(100,200), cor=F)

        2-sample test for equality of proportions 
        without continuity correction

data:  c(20, 42) out of c(100, 200)
X-squared = 0.040661, df = 1, p-value = 0.8402
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.10660654  0.08660654
sample estimates:
prop 1 prop 2 
  0.20   0.21
```

This test is equivalent to a chi-squared test on a $2\times 2$ table
of counts. The P-values are identical.

```
prop.test(c(20,42), c(100,200), cor=F)$p.val
[1] 0.8401929
TAB1 = rbind(c(20,42),c(80,158));  TAB1
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   20   42
[2,]   80  158
chisq.test(TAB1,cor=F)$p.val
[1] 0.8401929
```

(2) $\hat p_1 = 20/100$ is significantly different from $\hat p_2 = 66/200$ at 5% level.

```
prop.test(c(20,66), c(100,200), cor=F)

        2-sample test for equality of proportions 
        without continuity correction

data:  c(20, 66) out of c(100, 200)
X-squared = 5.5097, df = 1, p-value = 0.01891
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.23194639 -0.02805361
sample estimates:
prop 1 prop 2 
  0.20   0.33
```

Comment: In the output of prop.test, the use of uppercase chi, X, rather than $\chi$ is probably due to ubiquitous availability of the X font. If you were publishing the $\chi$-squared statistic you would use $\chi$?

Comment: Yes, for a symbol I'd use $\chi$ or $\chi^2,$ but maybe better to say 'chi-squared statistic'. As you've noted there is no standard symbol. Sometimes I've seen $Q$ or $H.$